# Facebook Send button - manipulating the popunder div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, cross-domain

I am positioning the facebook 'send' button at the right edge of my page.
Therefore, when clicking it, and opening the underlying div (where the details of the send information are being filled) it opens to the left, extruding from the page width.
This is why I am trying to move this div to the left when it is opened.
Unfortunately I dont see a way to this without moving also the button since both of these elements are loaded in a cross-domain Iframe (from facebook).

Is there any way to position the popunder div separately from the button?

Will CORS help me achieve this goal?

Many thanks,

junkycoder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, you could style it like this:

```
.fb_iframe_widget_lift {
overflow: visible !important;
width: 475px !important;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: -475px !important;
border:20px solid black;
padding: 10px;
height: 225px !important; /* Edit if you want to restore native border */
}
.fb-send{
  float:right;
}
```

You can check it in here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GekKs

It's not perfect, but it does the job.